# How to append closest value in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a `list =[15,3,12,9,8,7]` and k=18 . sorted in reverse list = [15,12,9,,8,7,3]

i want to append the first value i.e 15 of my list in arr1[] and second value of list i.e 12 in arr2[] and remove those values from my list

Then  we have [9,,8,7,3] in list so i want to append closest value of k-sum(arr1) in arr1 and k-sum(arr2) in arr2

so the array becomes `[15,3] and [12,7]` we will do this till n .

i dont know how to approach kindly help me thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
def find_ind_arr(arr):
    dif = k-sum(arr)
    tmp_lst = [abs(i-dif) for i in lst]
    return tmp_lst.index(min(tmp_lst))

lst = [15,12,9,8,7,3]
arr1 = [lst.pop(0)]
arr2 = [lst.pop(0)]

while lst:
    arr1.append(lst.pop(find_ind_arr(arr1)))
    arr2.append(lst.pop(find_ind_arr(arr2)))
print(arr1, arr2)
```